# How can add items in a gridview dynamically?

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

The pic shows how I need to organize my items in the gridview. First I tried creating a Linearlayout by code and adding my items, to organize it, but it doesn't works, because can do it by columns but not by rows.

I tried using tableview, but doesn't work either, then I start to look at Stackoverflow and I found the gridview, but looks I can't add new items by cod. I have to add the first item button "add category" and when I do click on it, I have to add new items from this button and the button need moves of position. I tried with wrap content the gridview but doesn't looks good.

This is my adapter of the gridview package Adaptador;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Contexto de la aplicación
    private Context mContext;


    // Array de identificadores

    String nombre = "";



    public  Integer[] mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] cosa,String nom) {
        mThumbIds = cosa;
        mContext = c;
        nombre = nom;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {




        final LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        linear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        if (convertView == null) {


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, parent, false);


            TextView edittitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag("titulocategoria");
            Button btncate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoria1);
            edittitulo.setId(position);
            edittitulo.setText(nombre);
            btncate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                }
            });






        }


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

I don't know why, when I set on setOnItemClickListener never works.

Comment: take onClickListener out of if condition.

Comment: You should use `RecylerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: @sohailehmad can you answer the question please? I Would like to give you the points.